# Calling QApplication::processEvents from a slot causes same slot to be called again

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

There is a signal `some_signal` which is connected to a slot `on_some_signal` using a queued connection. Like this:

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(some_signal()), receiver, SLOT(on_some_signal()), 
        Qt::QueuedConnection|Qt::UniqueConnection);
```

The `on_some_signal` calls some heavy machinery inside of which `QApplicaton::processEvents` is called. When `QApplicaton::processEvents` is called, it triggers the same slot again.

Question is, how to prevent the slot from being called twice? The signal is emitted only once.

Comment: Calling `QApplicaton::processEvents()` may lead to unpredictable behavior. Try to avoid it. If you can't, reconsider your design.

Answer (score 3):

It's expected behaviour. `QApplicaton::processEvents` invokes mechanisms that fall asynchronous handlers (slots). Essentially your slot was called from inside of that mechanism, and it would call all unprocessed events again, starting with itself. Its purpose to be called from inside of  thread, not from slot handlers.

Comment: My only complaint about this reasoning is that `QDialog::exec` always calls `processEvents` and almost all dialogs are launched from some sort of user interaction (thus inside a slot).  So this issue does not present itself every time `processEvents` is called in a slot.  But I have (recently) had this problem myself.  **My fix:** `QTimer::singleShot(0, lambda_with_processEvents);` inside of the slot.  I'm not sure why the timer/lambda combination does not reproduce the issue when my original code (the signal came from a remote object) did.